# If an object is of specified Type, can it still be null?

Tags: c#

If you check an object for its type and find out it is of the type you checked for, and you convert it to this type, can this type still be null after conversion ?

The code quality scanning app I'm running is complaining about the following:

```
if (tx.Tag is ExtendedNodeInfo && ty.Tag is ExtendedNodeInfo)
{
    var tagX = tx.Tag as ExtendedNodeInfo;
    var tagY = ty.Tag as ExtendedNodeInfo;                                        
    // HP Fortify scan says the below line's use of tagX/Y can be null.
    // If I add null checks below for taX/Y, Resharper says 
    // its redundant as its always not null
    return tagX.Ordinal.CompareTo(tagY.Ordinal);
}
```

Comment: `tagX/Y`` can be null what i see

Comment: maybe Ordinal is null?

Comment: If the value of tx.Tag is null then it will fail the first condition, therefore making a null check unnecessary - causing Resharper to flag it. But it is _technically_ possible for tagX/tagY to be null - which causes Fortify to flag it. Try putting a null check around the code snippet - that might keep both happy. e.g. `if (tx.Tag != null && ty.Tag != null){`

Comment: as a guess: HP Fortify sees `var tagX = tx.Tag as ExtendedNodeInfo;` and knows that `tagX` may be null. Resharper looks further at `if (tx.Tag is ExtendedNodeInfo` and knows that it will not happen.

Comment: @HansKesting: One could also argue that HP Fortify is watching out for a race condition, but Resharper is ignoring it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `tx.Tag` doesn't change its value, that's fine - but presumably the code quality scanner doesn't know that. It's generally better to use `as` for this, so that you only evaluate the property once, only perform the type test once, and then just check the references:

```
var tagX = tx.Tag as ExtendedNodeInfo;
var tagY = ty.Tag as ExtendedNodeInfo;
if (tagX != null && tagY != null)
{
    return tagX.Ordinal.CompareTo(tagY.Ordinal);
}
```

Comment: Just to complement, when you use the "as" converter your variable will be null if it can't convert. That's why it's saying that it can be null.

Comment: @Luiz but why would the conversion with `as` fail?

Comment: @JonSkeet Although I agree that it's preferable to use `as` and check for null, the code written is perfectly valid and should not generate that warning, IMO

Comment: @jeroenh: Suppose that after the `if` condition is evaluated, the value of `tx.Tag` changes to a string, or something like that - then `tagX` will be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tx.Tag is ExtendedNodeInfo && ty.Tag is ExtendedNodeInfo)
```

After this line, you have the following guarantees:

- `tx` and `ty` are not null (otherwise, a `NullReferenceException` would have been thrown)
- both `tx.Tag` and `ty.Tag` are of type `ExtendedNodeInfo`, so you can safely cast them to that type, so in your example both `tagX` and `tagY` are guarantueed to be not null

If the warning is about the use of txTag or tyTag, then this is wrong, IMO. But possibly, the warning is about the unchecked dereferencing of `Ordinal`?

Comment: Or more precisely, and I suspect that's where the warning is coming from: "After this line, *assuming no other thread writes to tx.Tag or ty.Tag*, you have the following guarantees". I have no idea if either product the OP uses takes threading into account.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt: It doesn't even need to be a write to `tx.Tag` - it just needs to be that property returning a different value. It could return a random value each time it's accessed :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: True indeed. You try to avoid the tiny little nails on the road while forgetting to look at the massive big rock in front of you :)